# modulus function problem...

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$|x|-|x-1|+|x-2|=\sqrt 5$$

Can anybody tell me how to solve this? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

**hint**: Consider $4$ separate cases: $1): x < 0$, $2): 0 \leq x < 1$, $3): 1 \leq x < 2$, and $4): 2 \leq x$